# jQuery slideToggle keeps repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle

I have a simple jQuery code that looks like this:

```
$( "#resp-navigation" ).one("click", function() {
    $( "#navigation" ).slideToggle(500);
});
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="resp-navigation"> ... </div>
<nav id="navigation"> ... </nav>
```

My problem is that when I click on the #resp-navigation div, the #navigation keeps toggling. Does anyone meybe know why?

Thanks.

Comment: assume, that this is not all you code. as your example works as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your intention is to have the '#navigation' div toggle each time someone clicks on the '#resp-navigation' div, then:

This: `$( "#resp-navigation" ).one`

Should be: `$( "#resp-navigation" ).on`

And then it works fine in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/us0dm62c/

If, however, your intention is to only ever have the '#navigation' div toggle once (so it disappears and cannot be shown again), then your code does exactly that with no modifications, as you can see in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gktnhhm5/

Answer (score 0):

As @trevor said, it should be on('click'), not one('click').

If you are seeing it ping ponging my guess is you have another on-click listener assigned elsewhere in the code that is doing the same thing.

Comment: This should be a comment on @trevor's answer; this is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using .one(*). Using like `$(".btn1").click(function(){...}` will work for multiply click.